# JavaScript and browser PDF support detection

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, browser, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to get to work PDF support detection based on a browser where application is running.

First application is checking if a browser is not running on a mobile device. That part works fine - I'm getting `Globals.bAllowPdfPreview = true`

Then I try to execute code below

```
if (Globals.bAllowPdfPreview && window.navigator && window.navigator.mimeTypes)
{
    Globals.bAllowPdfPreview = !!_.find(window.navigator.mimeTypes, function (oType) {
        return oType && 'application/pdf' === oType.type;
    });

    if (!Globals.bAllowPdfPreview)
    {
        Globals.bAllowPdfPreview = (typeof window.navigator.mimeTypes['application/pdf'] !== 'undefined');
    }
}
```

It works fine on Chrome but I'm not able to get it to work on FireFox or IE11 - it fails on both statements to verify.

Any tips why is not working?

Comment: What is "Globals.bAllowPdfPreview" and why is detecting "PDF support" important for you?

Comment: `Globals.bAllowPdfPreview` is a boolean, which I have mentioned in the OP. "PDF support" means that browser support PDF mime-type, which I expect code above will verify.

Comment: @Ryan I'm trying to detect PDF support similar way like they do: http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/All/

Comment: Apparently Mozilla removed the `application/PDF` MIME type from Firefox's `navigator.mimeTypes` object. How about IE11?

Comment: All the latest major desktop browsers, expect IE11, can view PDF files natively. Why are you checking for "support PDF mime-type"?

Comment: It came up from an existing (old) code to validate if a browser supports PDF preview and I had to try to fix it - apparently this is not a code problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came up that Firefox is not working as Mozilla removed the `application/pdf` MIME type from `navigator.mimeTypes` object and for IE11 only `application/futuresplash` and `application/x-shockwave-flash` are available by default.